# android custom layout to display folder path structure

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am developing an Android app.
What I want to do is showing file path like "> dir1 > dir2 > dir3 > file.txt".
The seperator ">" is an Image.

My problem is...
The width is limited.
For example...

|----- limited width -----|

| > dir1 > dir2 > dir3 > file.txt

The upper case exceeds the limited width.
So I should change to below UI

|----- limited width -----|

| ... > dir3 > file.txt

This means that if the full path exceeds the width, I should truncate the front of dir name dynamically, but not at all.
I should show the path names as possible.

I am trying with a custom layout which extends LinearLayout and pathList.
I add the path into my custom layout using the "addView()" method.

But it's not easy, because I have no experience of custom view.

I don't know my try is the right way or not.

Is there any idea or library?

Comment: Why are you using _>_ as a image ? You can simply use textView or append that operator in string path.

Comment: It just... designer want to use it as an image...... Yes, I can use "drawableStart", but anyway it doesn't matter.